# How can pass a entity or object as paramater in stored-procedure?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I don't know if that possible or not. I need to know how I can pass a entity as paramter in stored-procedure, that to avoid a problem like update same column of data not all column.
Excatly, If the full data updated or the procedure do not the update if there is problem found.

Example:
If I have a entity lik Person

```
class Person
{
     int Id {get;set;}
     string FirstName {get;set;}
     string LastName {get;set;}
     int age {get;set;}
     String Address {get;set;}
}
```

and I ask if I can pass this person as paramater in stored-procedure like this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE UpdatePerson (PN$Person PERSON%Type) IS
BEGIN
// do something
END;
```

that what I want to know, something like that.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with a concrete example of what you are trying to achieve or the problem you are trying to solve as its currently not clear what the problem is.

Comment: Oracle does not have a `class`. Please [edit] your question with something that will actually compile in Oracle; or if you are trying to pass a class from another language then update the question's tags with the other language(s) you are using.

Comment: I know oracle does not have class just I wrote that class for example in c# to say this entity from .net application or java application.
But I ask for the last part of code in oracle or sql server can accept a entity as paramater.

Comment: Are you familiar with Oracle's CREATE TYPE which is a data-definition language (DDL) statement. CREATE PROCEDURE is also a DDL statement. The CREATE TYPE statement lets you "wrap" a java class. I don't know if it also lets you wrap a C# class. Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

> [whether] code in oracle ... can accept a entity as paramater

If you have a table called PERSON you can define a procedure in Oracle which takes a parameter with the same projection as the table using the %ROWTYPE syntax:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE UpdatePerson (PN$Person PERSON%rowtype) IS
```